# Is there a good tutorial on writing a custom language module for PLT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, dsl, racket

Where should I start to write a custom language for PLT? Is there any information on the net (or maybe information in the manual I'm overseeing?) Or are the existing language packs the best reference for such a task?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book - [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/) might be a good place to start, especially chapter XII "Domain-Specific Languages and Metaprogramming". It uses PLT Scheme for the code samples, and the entire book is a worthy read.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Seems that it gives me the first steps I need.

Comment: That would be chapter 12 (XII)

Answer (score 3):

This may be no longer relevant, but worth a mention.  While PLAI is a good read, it is intended to be a general textbook on programming languages.  If you want to get some specific details about creating new languages in PLT, then you are likely to be interested in a tutorial that I have given in [DEFUN09](http://www.defun2009.info/blog/tutorial-schedule/implementing-domain-specific-languages-with-plt-scheme/) about this.  I didn't make this public yet, since there is still some more work to do to get it in shape, but it is likely to be a useful resource if you're interested in this.  (I will eventually turn it into a guide that will be included with the PLT documentation.)  If you're interested, you can email me -- I'll send you a copy and I'll also be happy to get any feedback.